# Add text if blank otherwise leave value

Tags: excel

I am trying to add the text `Unknown` to a column if the cell is blank and if there is a value or text in the cell, then to leave it. Everything I have tried adds the text if blank, but it also writes over cells that had values already.

```
Column E
 Graduate
 Undergraduate
 (BLANK)
 Community
```

I have tried:

```
= IF (E2 <> "", E2, "Uknown")
= IF(ISBLANK(E2),"Uknown", E2)
= IF (NOT(ISBLANK(E2)), E2, "Unknown")
```

I messed up the cell values, but instead of adding `Unknown` it is appending zeroes.

Comment: You cannot do this with a formula in place.  You will need a helper column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have functions and data in the same cell.
Two options: 
 - add a new column for the funcions, and hide the original
 - or just simply replace empty cells with a value you like
[image]

Comment: Thank you. A much simpler solution than what I was trying. Understood regarding having functions and data in the same cell.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one line macro:

```
Sub unknown()
    Columns(5).SpecialCells(4).Value = "UNKNOWN"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this on another stackoverflow question. This may get you started. `=IF(AND(C3 = "", 0 < B3, B3 < 5000), "Order More", "Don't Order")`
 If you need nore information the question is listed as **excel vba code to replace empty cell with text based on adjacent cells number range** & answered by dcromley. Good Luck.